# Twitter sentiment analysis using Word2Vec

Tags: python, r, twitter

I have done following in R code as of now. I'm performing Twitter sentiment analysis (positive/negative) and I need to use classification model like: Logistic regression, SVM etc. As of now I've removed spaces, urls, emojis etc. Creating a new column "tidy tweet" and tokenizing it. Then I'm plotting the most common words on a bar plot. Now, I want to implement Word2Vec technique to tokenize the tweets and use it in my model (in R). But I don't know how to go about it. Can someone help me with that?
Link to csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARqEt75G1UcUpfdBtae1yEvurydeE2vr/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

```
library(xgboost)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(caret)
library(car)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
twitter_train<-read.csv("/Users/R/Final Training Data Set-twitter.csv")
text<-twitter_train$tweet
text <- tolower(text)
# Remove mentions, urls, emojis, numbers, punctuations, etc.
text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", text)
text <- gsub("https?://.+", "", text)
text <- gsub("\\d+\\w*\\d*", "", text)
text <- gsub("#\\w+", "", text)
text <- gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", text)
text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", text)
# Remove spaces and newlines
text <- gsub("\n", " ", text)
text <- gsub("^\\s+", "", text)
text <- gsub("\\s+$", "", text)
text <- gsub("[ |\t]+", " ", text)
#Create new column to store cleaned tweets
twitter_train["fix_text"] <- text
head(twitter_train$fix_text, 10)

# Convert to tidy format
tidy_text <- twitter_train %>%
  select(id,label,fix_text) %>%
  #Tokenize the word from the tweets
  unnest_tokens(input = fix_text, output = word) %>%
  # Remove stop words
  anti_join(stop_words, by="word")

#Plotting most common words in corpus
tidy_text %>% # gives you a bar chart of the most frequent words found in the tweets
  count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  top_n(30) %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = word, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Count",
       x = "Unique words",
       title = "Most frequent words found in the dataset",
       subtitle = "Stop words removed from the list")
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use R package word2vec to embed your words and aggregate these embeddings to the tweet level by word2vec::doc2vec http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/100-word2vec-in-r

Or use R package doc2vec to embed your texts directly using a paragraph2vec model DM/DBOW and feed the tweet embeddings to your SVM  http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/103-doc2vec-in-r